# Remove Behind Text Shapes

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to delete the watermarks from Word documents.

I am trying with the macro to delete Behind Text shapes/images.

[image]

```
For Each s In ActiveDocument.Shapes
    s.Select
    If Selection.ShapeRange.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapBehind Then s.Delete
Next
```

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/ms-word-vba-macro-remove-behind-text-shapes/02924e61-38f6-47d4-9631-e5fd545e61e7. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Word calls watermarks are not shapes formatted as 'behind text' in the document body. Rather, they're shape objects in the document header. There is no simple way of differentiating between watermarks in the document header and other shape objects that might be there, since watermarks can consist of various different shape types. With that caveat, try the following macro for deleting the built-in watermarks that use text effects:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim HdFt As HeaderFooter, Shp As Shape
For Each HdFt In ActiveDocument.Sections.First.Headers
  For Each Shp In HdFt.Shapes
    If Shp.Type = msoTextEffect Then
      Shp.Delete
    End If
  Next
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me, it deletes all my images wrapped behind text. Are you sure the watermarks are truly a [shape object](https://github.com/OfficeDev/VBA-content/blob/master/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/shapes-object-word.md)? Ms word has a [built-in](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-a-watermark-f90f26a5-2101-4a75-bbfe-f27ef05002de) function for watermarks.

If you want to remove it programmatically, there is already [codes available](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/vba-to-add-delete-watermark-on-each-page/7f73b736-5da3-4eea-9af1-4629addcd4b4) (this on adds protection so you'd have to tinker with it). It's getting more complicated than only Shapes as it is a [Word building block object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.buildingblock).

To be brief, here is some code to give you an insight on what to do if it is a watermark object. You could count the header shapes to delete all the corresponding indexes or you would know the name list of all the headers of which Word gave random names. (I used the macro recorder to answer quickly some bits of the code are not entirely useful, mainly all the .Select methods)

```
 ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader 'header mode
 ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes(1).Select 'Select the first shape from headers (possibly a watermark)

 ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument 'normal mode
    ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Range.Select 'selects section 1
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
    Selection.HeaderFooter.Shapes.AddTextEffect(PowerPlusWaterMarkObject44576390, "CUSTOM WATERMARK", "Calibri", 1, False, False, 0, 0).Select 'Create a custom watermark
    Selection.ShapeRange.Name = "PowerPlusWaterMarkObject44576390" 'weird name created automatically by MS Word

    ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes(1).Delete 'delete header shape by index ".Shapes(1).Delete"
    Selection.HeaderFooter.Shapes("PowerPlusWaterMarkObject44576390").Delete 'deleting knowing the name
```

Keep in my mind this may not work if the watermark is some other object.

Hope you find it useful!

Comment: When watermarks are added, Word adds them to all three header types - your code only attempts to delete them from the primary header. The "PowerPlusWaterMarkObject44576390" reference is document-specific, so would not work for watermarks in other documents.

Comment: Thank you @macropod for your help, for the three types of headers, would he have to do (according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdheaderfooterindex) Primary, FirstPage and EvenPages for the Delete action? Also, maybe I should have put that it's document specific but that was the point, your code seem to have the answer to how to loop through all shapes. Thanks